# cange Bottom navigation bar and pageview if i'm not be in the principal pages

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

it is possible in flutter to have a main page with a pageview and that inside this pageview there are 5 main pages, that this page view is connected with the bottom navigation bar in the main page, but for example if in one of those 5 pages I navigate to another screen, it is possible that in that screen to which I navigate the main bottom navigation bar is shown and that when I press any of the buttons of the bottom navigation bar it redirects me to the corresponding screen no matter that I am not in one of the 5 main pages of the page view, I am managing the state with provider.

Answer (score 1):

If i get it correct - yes you can do it.
You have to do 5 separated widgets (as your pages) and you can show them in one main widget doing something like this:

```
child: Column(
    children: <Widgets>[
        Widget1();
        Widget2();
        Widget3();
        Widget4();
        Widget5();
    ]
)
```

For the bottom navigation bar you can create another widget to navigate to the exact page with Navigator, and use it in every page you need to.